# Mean Intensity of each object of an image by MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image with uint8 data type. There are several numbers of objects (say 6 to 7) in that image. I want to calculate mean Intensity of each objects and store them for further use. How can I do that?

```
s  = regionprops(image,'MeanIntensity');
intensitydata = cat(1, s.MeanIntensity);
```

I have tried this one. But it gives me following error

> Error in regionprops (line 154)
>   [I,requestedStats,officialStats] = ParseInputs(imageSize,
>   varargin{:});

Comment: how are the objects represented? do you need to detect them as well? please provide an example image and inputs you have. As you question currently stands it is unclear.

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/HbKhmVO.png) 
A sample image is provided here. I want just the mean intensity values of the objects. If there are 6 objects I want 6 mean intensity values for each objects. That's all. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the `'MeanIntensity'` you need to provide two inputs to `regionprops`: the label image and the intensity image.

```
bw = img > 0; %// a mask indicating the locations of the objects
lb = bwlabel(bw); %// label each object
s = regionprops( lb, img, 'MeanIntensity');
```